# mysql open_files_limit change fail

Tags: mysql

my mysql variables `open_files_limit` is now 5000;

I want to change it to 1024 for whatever reason.
According to the mysql doc:

step1: I tried to write it directly in the mysql config file:
But,it didn't work after mysql restart.

step2: According to the formulas in the mysql doc.
I check the relevant variables:

SO,please help.Thank you.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Q3L.png)

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Q3L.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZM64.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHAXU.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TrWm.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEu7d.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBNka.png)

Comment: [open_files_limit=5000]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Q3L.png)
[assign open_files_limit in mysql config]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZM64.png)
[formulas in the mysql doc]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHAXU.png)
[ulimit -n]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TrWm.png)
[max_connections]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEu7d.png)
[table_open_cache]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBNka.png)